# Formating user input into a txt file

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to format these 2 user inputs into a file on seperate lines I know I have to us the \n to use a new line but I keep getting errors with where I put it, is there another way to get each user input on a new line?

'''

```
def userfile():
   text = []

   text.append(input("Enter sentence 1: "))
   text.append(input("Enter sentence 2: "))

   file = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "sample2.txt"), "w")
   file.writelines(text)
   file.close()

   newfile = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0],"sample2.txt"), "r")
   print(newfile.read())

def main():
   #txtfile()
   userfile()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append it at the end of user input:

```
text.append(input("Enter sentence 1: ") + "\n")
text.append(input("Enter sentence 2: ") + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this.

**Explictly Looping**

```py
def userfile():
    text = []

    text.append(input("Enter sentence 1: "))
    text.append(input("Enter sentence 2: "))

    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "sample2.txt"), "w") as file:
        for line in text:
            print(line, file=file)
    ... # etc.
```

**Creating a Single String**

```py
def userfile():
    text = []

    text.append(input("Enter sentence 1: "))
    text.append(input("Enter sentence 2: "))

    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "sample2.txt"), "w") as file:
        print('\n'.join(text), file=File)
    ... # etc.
```

**Appending a Newline to the Input**

```py
def userfile():
    text = []

    text.append(input("Enter sentence 1: ") + '\n')
    text.append(input("Enter sentence 2: ") + '\n')

    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "sample2.txt"), "w") as file:
        file.writelines(text)
    ... # etc.
```